# $\mathbb{C}[x+y,xy]$ is isomorphic to $C[z,w]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am doing questions on polynomial rings, working out of Dummit and Foote.  I am struggling on a question.

Let $\mathbb{C}[x+y,xy]$ be the polynomial ring in two variables $x+y$ and $xy$ over the complex numbers.  Show that $\mathbb{C}[x+y,xy] \cong \mathbb{C}[z,w]$.

To prove this, there is a pretty obvious map $\varphi: \mathbb{C}[z,w] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x+y,xy]$ where we say $\varphi(z) = x+y$ and $\varphi(w) = xy$ and then extend the map $\varphi$ to make it into a ring homomorphism.  Given a polynomial $p(x+y,xy)$, I just say that $\varphi(p(z,w)) = p(x+y,xy)$.  So $\varphi$ is surjective.  I do not know how to obtain injective.  I let $\varphi(p(z,w)) = 0$, and the ring homomorphism implies that $p(x+y,xy) = 0$.  I think that I need to show that $x+y$ and $xy$ are relatively prime in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, but I do not know if that is sufficient.  I appreciate any help on this question.  Thanks.

Comment: This is the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomial in two variables.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials